# SSLHandshakeException Behavior in Certificate Chains

Tags: java, ssl

I've implemented certificate pinning using stored certificates of this certificate chain:

- Certificate 1: Cloud Platform
- Certificate 2: Verizon (Intermediate CA)
- Certificate 3: Baltimore (Root CA)

I've noticed a strange behavior though:

- Behavior 1 (Expected): If I only pinned certificate 1, I'll get an
  SSLHandshakeException error because I need to include all
  certificates in the chain.
- Behavior 2 (Unexpected?): If I only pinned certificate 2 which is the
  intermediate CA, I won't get any SSLHandshakeException error at all.

Would you know if behavior 2 is expected and if yes, why? I was under the impression that all certificates in the chain should be used else I'll get an SSLHandshakeException. Thanks!

**Updated with Code**

```
class SSLPinning {

void exec() {

    // Open InputStreams for each certificate
    InputStream baltimoreInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("baltimore.cer");
    InputStream hcpmsInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("hcpms_cert.cer");
    InputStream verizonInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("verizon.cer");

    try {

        // CertificateFactory has the method that generates certificates from InputStream
        // Default type for getInstance is X.509
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        // Create Certificate objects for each certificate
        Certificate baltimoreCertificate = cf.generateCertificate(baltimoreInputStream);
        Certificate hcpmsCertificate = cf.generateCertificate(hcpmsInputStream);
        Certificate verizonCertificate = cf.generateCertificate(verizonInputStream);

        // Create KeyStore and load it with our certificates
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        //keyStore.setCertificateEntry("hcpms", hcpmsCertificate);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("intermediate", verizonCertificate); //surprisingly, it works with just using the intermediate CA
        //keyStore.setCertificateEntry("root", baltimoreCertificate);

        // Create a TrustManagerFactory using KeyStore -- this is responsible in authenticating the servers
        // against our stored certificates
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext using TrustManagerFactory -- this will generate the SSLSocketFactory we will use
        // during HTTPS connection
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        URL url = new URL("https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com/");
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        httpsURLConnection.connect();
        System.out.print("Server authentication successful");

    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {
        System.out.println("Server authentication failed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It is unclear how you implemented certificate pinning - edit your question and add the code. Anyway if you implemented the code you should know if and why the certificate validation failed...

Comment: I've updated the post with code.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that for verifying a certificate a trusted chain have to be present (a trusted certificate and all intermediate certificates up to the server/leaf-certificate). However most SSL/TLS server do not send the complete chain to you. You sometimes only get the leaf-certificate (no intermediate or root certificate; you can see this e.g. in a Wireshark traffic dump).

Other server may send you the leaf-certificate and all/some intermediate certificates but no root certificate.

In such a case it is crucial that your local truststore contains the missing certificates to build up the complete chain.

By your observation I assume that the server does only send the leaf-certificate without intermediate and root certificate. Therefore for a successful verification your truststore have to include the intermediate certificate as trusted certificate to make it work (otherwise this certificate would be missing). I would recommend to include both the root and the intermediate certificate into your truststore.

BTW: Servers not sending the intermediate CA certificate can also be a server configuration problem. Usually I would recommend to configure a server to send leaf and intermediate certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Robert. That was my expectation too -- that the whole certificate chain be stored for the pinning to work. That's why I find it a little strange that when I try just pinning the intermediate certificate without the leaf and the root certificates, it's still being authenticated without exceptions. For reference here's a screenshot of the certificate chain (I believe the server is sending the whole certificate chain):

![Certificate chain](https://ibin.co/2yFJQAPIL2AD.png).

Would you have any idea on this behavior?